# Reuse tomcat threads while waiting "long" time

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat, nginx

**THE CONFIGURATION**
Web server : Nginx
App server  : Tomcat with default configuration of 200 request serving threads
Expected response time for my server : ~30 seconds(There are lots of third party dependencies)

**THE SCENARIO**
Every 10 seconds the application will need to generate the token for its use. The expected time for token generation is  around 5 seconds, but since its a third party system being contacted over network, this is obviously not consistent and can go up to 10 seconds.
During the token generation process, nearly 80% of the incoming requests per second will need to wait.

**WHAT I BELIEVE SHOULD HAPPEN**
Since the requests waiting for the token generation will have to wait a "long" time, there is no reason for these request serving to be reused to serve other incoming requests while waiting for token generation process to complete.
Basically, it would make sense if my 20% to keep being served. If the waiting threads are not being utilized for other requests, tomcat request serving limit will be reached and server would essentially choke, not really something any developer will like.

**WHAT I TRIED**
Initially I expected switching to tomcat NIO connector would do this job. But after looking at [this](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html#Connector_Comparison) comparison, I was really not hopeful. Nevertheless, I tried by forcing the requests to wait for 10 second and it did not work.
Now I am thinking on the lines that I need to, sort of, shelve the request while its waiting and need to signal the tomcat that this thread  is free to reuse. Similarly, I will need tomcat to give me a thread from its threadpool when the request is ready to be moved forward. But I am blindsided on how to do it or even if this is possible.

Any guidance or help?

Comment: You said "*During the token generation process, nearly 80% of the incoming requests per second will need to wait.*", it is not obvious for everyone whether these 80% of incoming request are incoming requests to your application or request you have sent to 3rd party system for token generation. I think you need to clarify this whole in your complete answer as when you are talking about which thing, because like I said it may be not obvious for everyone, please clarify and you may have greater chances of getting a solution.

Comment: @hagrawal 80% of incoming requests will be waiting for third party.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need an asynchronous servlet but you also need asynchronous HTTP calls to the external token generator. You will gain nothing by passing the requests from the servlet to an ExecutorService with a thread pool if you still create one thread somewhere per token request. You have to decouple threads from HTTP requests so that one thread can handle multiple HTTP requests. This can be achieved with an asynchronous HTTP client like Apache [Asynch HttpClient](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-asyncclient-dev/index.html) or [Async Http Client](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client).

First you have to create an asynchronous servlet like this one

```
public class ProxyService extends HttpServlet {

    private CloseableHttpAsyncClient httpClient;

    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        httpClient = HttpAsyncClients.custom().
                setMaxConnTotal(Integer.parseInt(getInitParameter("maxtotalconnections"))).             
                setMaxConnPerRoute(Integer.parseInt(getInitParameter("maxconnectionsperroute"))).
                build();
        httpClient.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        try {
            httpClient.close();
        } catch (IOException e) { }
    }

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        AsyncContext asyncCtx = request.startAsync(request, response);
        asyncCtx.setTimeout(ExternalServiceMock.TIMEOUT_SECONDS * ExternalServiceMock.K);       
        ResponseListener listener = new ResponseListener();
        asyncCtx.addListener(listener);
        Future<String> result = httpClient.execute(HttpAsyncMethods.createGet(getInitParameter("serviceurl")), new ResponseConsumer(asyncCtx), null);
    }

}
```

This servlet performs an asynchronous HTTP call using Apache Asynch HttpClient. Note that you may want to configure the maximum connections per route because as per RFC 2616 spec HttpAsyncClient will only allow a maximum of two concurrent connections to the same host by default. And there are plenty of other options that you can configure as shown in [HttpAsyncClient configuration](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-asyncclient-dev/httpasyncclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/nio/client/AsyncClientConfiguration.java). HttpAsyncClient is expensive to create, therefore you do not want to create an instace of it on each GET operation.

One listener is hooked to the AsyncContext, this listener is only used in the example above to handle timeouts.

```
public class ResponseListener implements AsyncListener {

    @Override
    public void onStartAsync(AsyncEvent event) throws IOException {
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete(AsyncEvent event) throws IOException {
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(AsyncEvent event) throws IOException {
        event.getAsyncContext().getResponse().getWriter().print("error:");
    }

    @Override
    public void onTimeout(AsyncEvent event) throws IOException {
        event.getAsyncContext().getResponse().getWriter().print("timeout:");
    }

}
```

Then you need a consumer for the HTTP client. This consumer informs the AsyncContext by calling `complete()` when `buildResult()` is executed internally by HttpClient as a step to return a `Future<String>` to the caller `ProxyService` servlet.

```
public class ResponseConsumer extends AsyncCharConsumer<String> {

    private int responseCode;
    private StringBuilder responseBuffer;
    private AsyncContext asyncCtx;

    public ResponseConsumer(AsyncContext asyncCtx) {
        this.responseBuffer = new StringBuilder();
        this.asyncCtx = asyncCtx;
    }

    @Override
    protected void releaseResources() { }

    @Override
    protected String buildResult(final HttpContext context) {
        try {
            PrintWriter responseWriter = asyncCtx.getResponse().getWriter();
            switch (responseCode) {
                case javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse.SC_OK:
                    responseWriter.print("success:" + responseBuffer.toString());
                    break;
                default:
                    responseWriter.print("error:" + responseBuffer.toString());
                }
        } catch (IOException e) { }
        asyncCtx.complete();        
        return responseBuffer.toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCharReceived(CharBuffer buffer, IOControl ioc) throws IOException {
        while (buffer.hasRemaining())
            responseBuffer.append(buffer.get());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResponseReceived(HttpResponse response) throws HttpException, IOException {        
        responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    }

}
```

The web.xml configuration for ProxyService servlet may be like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0" metadata-complete="true">
  <display-name>asyncservlet-demo</display-name>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>External Service Mock</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>ExternalServiceMock</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Proxy Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>ProxyService</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>maxtotalconnections</param-name>
      <param-value>200</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>maxconnectionsperroute</param-name>
      <param-value>4</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>serviceurl</param-name>
      <param-value>http://127.0.0.1:8080/asyncservlet/externalservicemock</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>External Service Mock</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/externalservicemock</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Proxy Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/proxyservice</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

And a mock servlet for the token generator with a delay in seconds may be:

```
public class ExternalServiceMock extends HttpServlet{

    public static final int TIMEOUT_SECONDS = 13;
    public static final long K = 1000l;

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(rnd.nextInt(TIMEOUT_SECONDS) * K);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
        final byte[] token = String.format("%10d", Math.abs(rnd.nextLong())).getBytes(ISO_8859_1);
        response.setContentType("text/plain");
        response.setCharacterEncoding(ISO_8859_1.name());
        response.setContentLength(token.length);
        response.getOutputStream().write(token);
    }

}
```

You can get a [fully working example at GitHub](https://github.com/sergiomt/asynchttpservice-example).

Answer (score 1):

This problem is essentially the reason so many "reactive" libraries and toolkits exist.

It's not a problem that can be solved by tweaking or swapping out the tomcat connector.
You basically need to remove all blocking IO calls, replacing them with non-blocking IO will likely require rewriting large parts of the application.
Your HTTP server needs to be non-blocking, you need to be using a non blocking API to the server(like servlet 3.1) and your calls to the third party API need to be non blocking.
Libraries like Vert.x and RxJava provide tooling to help with all of this.

Otherwise the only other alternative is to just increase the size of the threadpool, the operating system already takes care of scheduling the CPU so that the inactive threads don’t cause too much performance loss, but there is always going to be more overhead compared to a reactive approach.

Without knowing more about your application it is hard to offer advice on a specific approach.

Comment: Well I guess the question boils down to : `For what situations does tomcat starts reusing the thread, and how can I generate such a situation?` . Haven't tried RxJava yet but will update once I run sample code.

Comment: Tomcat reuses the thread when control of the thread is returned to it, in your case the thread is blocked somewhere in your network call to the third party API.  Of course you need to wait for the result of that call to generate your response to the client. A reactive approach is rather than waiting for the response, you set up a callback function to generate the response. This way you can immediately return control of the thread back to tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

Using async servlet requests or reactive libraries (as mentioned in other answers) can help but will demand major architectural changes.

Another option is to separate token updates from token uses.

Here is a naive implementation:

```
public class TokenHolder {
    public static volatile Token token = null;
    private static Timer timer = new Timer(true);
    static {
        // set the token 1st time
        TokenHolder.token = getNewToken();

        // schedule updates periodically
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask(){
            public void run() {
                TokenHolder.token = getNewToken();
            }
        }, 10000, 10000);
    }
}
```

Now your requests can just use `TokenHolder.token` to access the service.

In a real application you probably will use a more advanced scheduling tool.